# Mahout parallel k-means in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mahout

Is it possible to run Mahout [k-means algorithm](https://mahout.apache.org/users/clustering/k-means-clustering.html) in parallel (multi-core) using Hadoop? How?

Mahout run using Hadoop **but it only uses one CPU**:

```
mahout org.apache.mahout.clustering.syntheticcontrol.kmeans.Job --input testdata --output end1200_50 --numClusters 1200 --t1 1000 --t2 500 --maxIter 50
Running on hadoop, using /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop and HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop
MAHOUT-JOB: /usr/local/mahout/mahout-examples-0.10.1-job.jar
[...]
```

---

My files are in HDFS `hadoop fs -ls /user/root/testdata`

```
Found 12 items
-rw-r--r--   1 root supergroup  373560731 2015-06-26 07:51 /user/root/testdata/16773m.mat.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 root supergroup  373819865 2015-06-26 07:51 /user/root/testdata/16786m.mat.txt
[...]
```

my mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>
 <property>
  <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
  <value>localhost:54311</value>
 </property>


 <property>
  <name>mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum</name>
  <value>14</value>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name>mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum</name>
  <value>4</value>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name>mapred.child.java.opts</name>
  <value>-Xmx7000M</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Your data probably is not split appropriately. But make sure to benchmark with other tools. I found Mahout k-means to be incredibly slow!

Comment: Thank's @Anony-Mousse. All my files are around 500MB. do you recommend Fuzzy k-Means instead? or do you mean using something else than Mahout?

Comment: 500 MB, that easily fits into main memory. Use anything that is fast and *not* Hadoop.